# CAN-Bus Message confusion

Tags: can, bus, protocol, logic-analyzer, canopen

Can anyone tell me what the difference between these two sets of CAN Bus messages? This is from the manual of a Power Drive Unit (PDU) in the Cargo Handling System of a 747F (UPS Freight). This is the only place where the instructions are written as shown in #2. Additionally, Request #2 is the only request I can’t seem to get the intended response or result.

#1. Transmit the PDU Request Message on the CAN Bus as follows:

```
Arbitration ID: C5A005E  
Data (0-7): 0x 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
```

#2: Transmit the PDU Request Message on the CAN Bus as follows:

```
Arbitration ID: C5A005E  
Byte 7 through 3: 0x00  
Byte 2: 0×40  
Byte 1: 0x00  
Byte 0: 0×40
```

*NOTE: Sorry to anyone who cant view images*

The following is a screenshot of the instructions for the initial Request for the programmed Part Number. In this step, The PDU responds as intended, with the Part Number, with one exception... the Identifier starts at "00" rather than "01".
Example Response: for PN 4345562

```
00 34 33 34 35 35 36 32  
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  
02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

[image]

Next page: instructions to program the Part Number to the EEPROM, if the recalled PN is not correct.
[image]

My main question is, what would the reasoning be for writing it as:

Byte 7 through 3: 0x00
Byte 2: 0×40
Byte 1: 0x00
Byte 0: 0×40

*-vs-*

0x 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00

UPDATE: CAN messages are transmitted in Little Endian Format.

Comment: `Data (0-7)` implies that the first message starts with byte 0 ... please do not post pictures of text ... doing so exudes people that cannot view pictures

Comment: Is this really CANopen? The term "PDU" is from J1939. CANopen has the term PDO. 29 bit identifiers also smells like J1939.

Comment: This certainly isn't CANopen. The CANopen CAN-IDs with function code 0 are limited to: 0 (NMT), 1 (global failsafe command), 0x71-0x76 (flying master) and 0x7F (indicate active master).

Comment: @Lundin PDU = Power Drive Unit

Comment: @joelcox No, it does not mean that in the context of CAN buses. It means Protocol Data Unit, an established term in the J1939 protocol. Best to stay clear of 3 letter abbreviations entirely.

Comment: @Lundin sorry, but in this case, it does.  I am literally testing a Collins Aerospace PDU… This is copied directly from their Manual which also covers all acronyms.

Comment: Are you sure this protocol isn't CANaerospace?

Comment: @joel You have neglected to mention if you are receiving the expected responses to the first PDU Request.  I interpret the fragment of the manual as saying "Transmit the first PDU, and you will get three CAN messages that contain the part number.  If you want to change the part number, transmit the second PDU request followed by three CAN messages containing the part number followed by the final PDU request".  My interpretation is that changing the part number is optional.

Comment: @Velvel , to be honest, I cant say with any degree of certainty what the protocol is. While the majority of an individual aircraft uses ARINC429, ARINC629, etc. the Cargo Handling Systems have their own Control Systems and are usually different than protocol. I can also confirm that using the instructions and sending an 8-Byte message as shown in the 1st request (0x 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00) it responds as anticipated.   If it matters I'm using PEAK Systems; PCAN View and PCAN-USB Adapter.

Comment: @SteveMathwig Are you saying you cant read my mind? HAHA I tried to be clear when I said #2 is the only request that I cant get intended response/result.  but I can definitely see where it is not. I will edit to clarify in main question.  Thanks

Comment: @joel It looks like the PDU does not generate any response to the set part number CAN messages.  To get the intended result, I assume you are sending the first PDU request to see if the part number has actually changed.

Comment: @SteveMathwig that is correct.

Comment: Either way, CANopen and CANaerospace both specify the first byte after the CAN-ID as byte 0, followed by bytes 1 to 7. And I'm willing to bet that any other sane CAN based protocol does it the same. Especially since CAN allows for 0 to 8 bytes of payload.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't super obvious if the data part of the CAN frame is enumerated as per "first received: byte 0" or as per "first received: byte 7". I don't think the CAN spec is clear here either, so they basically left all implementors of CAN to follow their own whims.

Since the amount of bytes can vary from 0 to 8, it would make sense to enumerate them with byte 0 starting first and "Data (0-7)" implies this too. But I've seen lots of documentation naming the first byte 7 as well.

Conclusion: there is no telling what to do based on the information you are given. The result could *either* be
`40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00` or
`00 00 00 00 00 40 00 40`
Ask for better documentation.

Comment: That actually makes more sense now… there is a note under a different set of 3 EEPROM messages that says “messages shown byte 7 through 0” which I assumed was only referring to those 3, since it base the message identifier “01, 02, 03” after byte 7. I will try this forth thing in the AM and will let you know.

Comment: adding a couple images.

Comment: I found out that messages are transmitted in Little Endian?